# gevent-socketio + Flask + Gunicorn

Tags: socket.io, flask, gevent, gunicorn

Can I use gevent-socketio with Flask, running under Gunicorn, and still enjoy the nice exception printing, debugger, and reload capability that Flask offers? How would my gunicorn worker and WSGI app class look like?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've got the exact same problem so I solved it by using watchdog.

```
pip install watchdog
```

together with this command:

```
watchmedo shell-command --patterns="*.py*;;*.less;*.css;*.js;*.txt;*.html" --recursive --command='kill -HUP `cat /tmp/gunicorn.pid` && echo "Reloading code" >> /tmp/gunicorn.log' ~/projectfolder
```

It requires (well, not really, but I point "Reloading code" into the same logfile so It's a nice thing to have) that you daemonize the gunicorn process, which I do like this:

**gunicorn_config.py**

```
workers = 2
worker_class = 'socketio.sgunicorn.GeventSocketIOWorker'
bind = '0.0.0.0:5000'
pidfile = '/tmp/gunicorn.pid'
debug = True
loglevel = 'debug'
errorlog = '/tmp/gunicorn.log'
daemon = True
```

Start the application:

```
gunicorn run:app -c gunicorn-config.py
```

View the log:

```
tail -f /tmp/gunicorn.log
```

From this point everything should be reloaded with each change in your project.
It's a bit complicated but since gunicorn with a worker (or the built in socketio-server) doesn't have any reloading capabilities I had to do it like this.

It's a different approach compared to the decorator solution in the other answer but I like to keep the actual code clean from development specific solutions. Both accomplish the same thing so I guess you'll just have to pick the solution you like. :)

Oh, as an added bonus you get to use the production server in development which means both environments match each other.

Comment: Nice. You don't need to daemonize gunicorn for that, though. A simple "-p /tmp/gunicorn.pid" suffices, which is nice because you get to see the logs in the console, plus you can ^C to stop.

I have to admit that for reasons of being lazy I liked the other answer better at first. However reloading in gunicorn requires a SIGHUP, and this seems like a decent-enough way of doing it.

I dislike having to run watchmedo in another window, though, and am actually thinking of putting a watchdog.observer inside my app.py (under `__name__ == '__main__'`, just for development)

Comment: well... adding watchdog to my specific project won't work -- I am using gevent. Guess I'll have to do it in a different process.

Comment: Nitzan, I was playing with creating a watchdog process together with the gunicorn process, but in the end I got so annoyed with weird results I simply use two windows. 

I like the daemonized setting because you can't accidently turn it off, and then tailing the log file is the same result as watching stdout :)

Comment: Yes, but you can't ^c it... I was also trying to generalize your idea by writing a watchdog 'trick' that will send sighup, which I gave up after realizing the gevent thing.

Comment: But you can use kill -9 `/tmp/gunicorn.pid` to turn it off. Simple aliases for all commands and it's not that much of a pain. I'm pretty sure I'll improve this mess when I get tired of it. ^^

Answer (score 5):

I've been looking into this subject lately. I don't think you can easily use autoreload feature with Flask + gevent-socket.io + Gunicorn. Gunicorn is a production server that does not allow such features natively.

However, I found a nice solution for my development server : user SocketIOServer provided with the library and a Flask snippet for autoreload. Here is the startup script (runserver.py) :

```
from myapp import app
from gevent import monkey
from socketio.server import SocketIOServer
import werkzeug.serving

# necessary for autoreload (at least)
monkey.patch_all()

PORT = 5000

@werkzeug.serving.run_with_reloader
def runServer():
    print 'Listening on %s...' % PORT
    ws = SocketIOServer(('0.0.0.0', PORT), app, resource="socket.io", policy_server=False)
    ws.serve_forever()

runServer()
```

This solution is inspired from : http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/34/

Comment: I just noticed that I lost the beautiful werkzeug debug page with this method... Looking into it.

Comment: Edited answer to include debug page. Used werkzeug.debug.DebuggedApplication : http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/debug/

Comment: Bad news : DebuggedApplication breaks websockets servicing :-( removing it.

Comment: Thanks. I like DebuggedApplication, and +1 just for that (don't care about WebSockets for this specific project). Reloading, however, seems to not work smoothly -- it will reload and restart Gunicorn, which will create more processes, leaving the old ones in place, and thus not allowing me to re-bind the port. Having looked at gunicorn code, it seems like there is a lot going on when you need to restart it, and the proper way would be to use SIGHUP.

Answer (score 3):

I've made some tweaks to Werkzeug debugger so it now works with socket.io namespaces, see below and enjoy :)

https://github.com/aldanor/SocketIO-Flask-Debug